# Pyside/PyQt - Program not responding but working in background

Tags: python, file-io, pyqt, beautifulsoup, pyside

I made a small program that gets a website and fetches the images and save them in a directory.

If I run the script it works fine, but the program freezes until it downloads every image on the website.

Here's part of the code.

```
def download(self):
    # gets the link
    thread = self.textbox_thread.text()
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(thread)
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        print 'wrong thread ID'

    # parse the HTML
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    soup = soup.body.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'postContainer replyContainer'})

    links = []
    for n in soup:
        # extracts image links
        test = n.find('div', attrs={'class':'fileText'})
        if test != None:
            link = test.find('a', href=True).get('href')
            links.append(link)

    for i, link in enumerate(links):
        # set the progress bar percentage
        value = int((i/ float(len(links)-1)*100))
        self.progressBar.setValue(value)

        # downloads the image
        file = urllib2.urlopen('http:' + link)

        # set the filename properly 
        board_thread = thread.replace("/","_").replace('thread',"").split("org")[1]
        name_of_file = board_thread.replace("__","_")[1:] + "_%04d" % (i + 1) + ".jpg"

        # saves the file
        complete_path = os.path.abspath(self.textbox_path.text()+name_of_file)
        output = open(complete_path, 'wb')
        output.write(file.read())
        output.close()
```

Comment: If the GUI is freezing then you'll have to show how you link the above function to the GUI. If it's not a gui problem then please be more specific.

Comment: It's the self.progressBar.setValue(value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is to use a `QThread` to rum the image loading in a separate thread. Although `QCoreApplication.processEvents` works, it is not as robust as using a separate thread (likely because you are forcing events to be processed while an event is being processed, a task that doesn't scale well when multiple functions call it.

Using `QThread` is well documented in the Qt docs online but if you have trouble finding this then post a comment and I will find specific links for you.

Comment: Yeah, I see. That was a hack of some sort. After reading about threading in Qt I came across QThread, I haven't tried it yet, no need to post any specific link, Qt is indeed very well documented. I choose you answer over my because it's the proper way to fix it and not a dirt hack.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

By adding: **QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()** in the loop. It manages to update the GUI before processing it again.